# multithreading and timer withing singleton

Tags: c#, timer

I implement a class with singleton like this

```
        public static SingleToneClass Instance
        {
            get
            {
                return Lazy.Value;
            }
        }
private static readonly Lazy<SingleToneClass > Lazy = new Lazy<SingleToneClass >(() => new RABTProxy());
```

within `SingleToneClass` there's a System.Timers timer

while trying to access the class from different threads the timer suddenly stop
any idea how to fix something like this , this is a sample of what am testing

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        //now create a timer each ten seconds create for create 
        var mainTimer = new Timer
        {
            Interval = 100
        };
        mainTimer.Elapsed += (sender, eventArgs) =>
        {

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    SingleToneClass.Instance.DoWwork();

                    Thread.Sleep(10);
                }

            });
        };

        mainTimer.Start();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

is it a good idea to use a timer in Singleton,any alternative

Comment: my guess is that you have found yourself in some sort of async deadlock. Also with the `while(true)` you maybe creating too many instances? I'd start by limiting to a couple tasks... 

If you are learning async... I suggest checking out these examples and downloading linqpad. I found these very helpful in the past:
https://github.com/saip106/linqpad-code-snippets/tree/master/Aysnc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comment says a timer every ten seconds but you're actually getting one ten times a second.

You then spawn new tasks on the thread pool that will run forever and will block with Thread.Sleep(). This will use all your thread pool threads and it will have to create new ones. BAD!

If all you want is for the DoWork to be called periodically you should skip the timer and launch a single task.

```
        Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                SingleToneClass.Instance.DoWwork();
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - just NuGet `System.Reactive` and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;`.

Then do this:

```
Observable
    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10.0))
    .Subscribe(_ =>  SingleToneClass.Instance.DoWwork());
```